# Changing text color for selected ListViewItem in metro UI application

Tags: xaml, listview, colors, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

How to get things together?

I'm working on Windows 8 metro application that contains ListView. My listview contains TextBlocks.
Something like this:

MyPage.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate">
     <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Goal, Mode=OneWay}"/>
     </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>

<ListView x:Name="ChainsList" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Chains}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedChain, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ChainsListViewItemStyle}">
</ListView>
```

I don't like default ListView colors for selected/deselected items, so in Designer mode I selected "Edit additional templates/Edit generated item container" and created own copy of ListViewItem style within StandardStyles.xml:

```
<Style x:Key="ChainsListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <!-- a lot of setters goes here -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                    <!-- description of visual states goes here (I changed some colors) -->
                    <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                       <!-- List view item structure details goes here -->
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now I want to change text color of my list view items depending on selection. If item selected TextBlock's color should be black. If item not selected - white.

**AND HERE IS A QUESTION:** where should I put logic for chaning TextBlock color? If somewhere in StandardStyles.xml then how I would assign it to TextBlock? If somewhere in list view item template then how should I get selection state?

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

Try adding these animations to the `SelectionStates` `VisualStateGroup` in your `ChainsListViewItemStyle` style:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="SelectedSwiping">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are no triggers in Winrt.

Comment: Well I've learnt something new! In that case you will need to use the VisualStateManager. I will update my answer.

Comment: Richard, in my initial post I placed style for ChainsListViewItemStyle. And in the text there is a comment:
<!-- description of visual states goes here (I changed some colors) -->
So I already played with visual states and changed colors. But I see no way how to reference TextBlock described in DataTemplate from visual states. The approach suggested by you won't work because actually I have couple TextBlocks and they should be of different colors. Changing ContentPresenters' property is not enough.